# How can I write a plugin for VS2010 using MEF?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, mef

I've seen lots of MEF code for plugging into custom apps, but I am yet to find out how to write a plugin for VS2010 using MEF. I was under the impression that the new IDE supported this.

Does anyone know if this is supported 'out of the box', or does it require an install. Does anyone have any links, tips, etc to get me started.

Comment: No, it wouldn't make sense.  a VS plugin built with MEF isn't a correct use case.

Comment: Dude not really following you for that one. Could you explain that a bit better. Or check yourself lest you wreck yourself. LOL

Answer (score 19, accepted):

MEF is the primary extension mechanism for extending the editor.  If you [install the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305cf4-2bea-43c0-91cd-1b853602dcc5&displaylang=en), there are a few new project samples set up to create editor extensions, found under `C# (or VB)->Extensibility`.  These include:

- Editor classifier – for providing syntax highlighting
- Editor margin – putting a margin along the sides of the editor, with arbitrary WPF content
- Editor text/viewport adornment – for putting WPF visuals into the editor

You can find overview documentation on MSDN: [Extending the editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885242.aspx), and [Editor extension points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885244.aspx).

Some samples you may want to look at: [editor samples on code.msdn.microsoft.com](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsx#EditorSamples), a couple more on [editorsamples.codeplex.com](http://editorsamples.codeplex.com/), and the source for [all the samples I've written](http://github.com/noahric).

I [blog about writing editor extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/noahric).  On there, you can find descriptions of most of the extensions I've written, along with more general posts about performance, design of the new editor, etc.

Questions posted on the [editor forum on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/threads) also are answered by various members of the editor team.