# How to integrate a custom antlr4-based language into Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, antlr4

I'd like to integrate my own custom language in Visual Studio.

I'd like to have:

- Syntax highlighting
- invoke a custom compiler, producing source files in another compilable language. These shall be compiled in a second phase.
- some simple tools like rename (*not* text based, so that a local variable is only renamed within scope), find code lines that reference this function/variable etc.
- Intellisense (code completion, suggest members, types etc.)

Is there a way to achieve this without too much effort?

I already discovered [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) (limited to a subset of antlr3) for eclipse, but need a similar tool based on antlr4 for visual studio?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211018/implementing-a-language-service-by-using-the-managed-package-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Extending Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165336.aspx) chapters in MSDN, especially

- [Language Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165099.aspx)
- [Projects and Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286970.aspx)
- [Editors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885118.aspx)

There are a few other blogs and tutorials on these topics as well:

- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33250/Writing-Your-First-Visual-Studio-Language-Service)
- [ANTLR and MyC](http://blog.280z28.org/archives/2008/10/21/)

And a few language services are open source and provide a great example:

- [IronPython](https://ironpython.codeplex.com/)
- [IronRuby](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/)
- [ASP.NET Web Stack](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Do you know if the mentioned language services use antlr4? I didn't find a clue at first glance. Starting from a "similar" language would be of great help.

Comment: Not specifically ANTLR4, but once you've generated your tokenizer/parser, then the work on top of it will be very similar. You need to build an AST eventually... The parsing code can be found here: https://ironpython.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#IronPython_Main/Languages/IronPython/IronPython/Compiler/Ast/ and http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Razor/Parser/

Comment: I'll have a look at it

Comment: And this plugin looks very promising...It's a language service for ANTLR inside Visual Studio. And it looks to be using ANTLR to do it. Reflector is your friend after extracting the vsix with your favorite unzipper... http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f or contact Sam directly on twitter (https://twitter.com/samharwell).

Comment: I'll also have a look. Antlr4 uses antlr3 to parse the grammar, but maybe that's not true for this extension. I'm using this extension myself - should have realized this as a good starting point myself...

Comment: Sams extension is quite complex. I'm pretty sure it would take months to understand... Maybe I'll start little by little...