# Implement a custom editor in Visual Studio 2008 or 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, text-editor

I'm trying to find documentation on how one would go about creating a custom editor plug-in for VS2008 or VS2010.

The file syntax I want to edit is from a tool called [TemplateMaschine](http://www.stefansarstedt.com/templatemaschine.html) by Stefan Sarstedt.

An example of the template syntax:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="System.Xml" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Xml" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Collections" %>
<%@ Argument Name="className" Type="string" %>
<%@ Argument Name="attributes" Type="ArrayList" %>

public class <%=className%>
{
<% foreach(string attr in attributes) { %>
public string <%=attr%>;
<% } %>
}
```

The most important editor features for me would be real-time syntax checking and code completion.  If we could get those features, it would save us THOUSANDS of man-hours.

Failing to incorporate a custom editor into Studio, maybe there is some open source text editor project out there that might be easy to extend for my purposes?  I've looked a little at Eclipse, but I would think code completion won't be an option (also, my Java stinks).  Another possibility might be extending the SharpDevelop text editor component.

Ideas and suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of options that work in VS2008 and VS2010.

There's Managed Babel, which is way to get these features automatically given a grammar (I believe the default uses flex/bison).  You can [read about it on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166570.aspx).

There's the managed package framework (MPF), which has a [managed language service (MLS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166360.aspx).  If you don't have a grammar already, this is probably the simplest route.

These both use the generalized solution of providing a language service, which is [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165697.aspx).

If you don't care about targeting VS2008, you can go straight to the new editor extensibility APIs in VS2010.  You can check out the [Ook! language sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ookLanguage), and read my answer to a question about [general editor extensibility in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688616/how-can-i-write-a-plugin-for-vs2010-using-mef/2688728#2688728).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've got a lot of reading to do!  ... and Ook? as a language -- there's a Terry Pratchett fan somewhere nearby ...

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to create your own DSL, take a look at the [Visual Studio Visualization and Modeling SDK](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsvmsdk).

If using TemplateMaschine isn't a complete necessity, take a look at t4 templates. They're built into Visual Studio, and tooling (such as Clarius Visual T4) is already available.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Aren't T4 templates a design-time methodology?  My templates are executed at run-time.  There seems to be some discussion of using T4 at run-time in .NET 4.0, but it seems highly preliminary.  Unless I'm mistaken?