# Visual Studio 2010 with Managed Extensiblity Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mef, capability

I've been looking into into MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework), but I am not entirely sure if it is something that I need and can help me accommplish what I need to do.

Can someone provide an easy to understand description of MEF, provides good resources and tutorials (aside from MSDN), and/or know if it can do the task I am trying to do under Visual Studio?

The task I am trying to do is to "log" a string of text to a text file whenever the user selects a string of text. I also need this functionality to run passively and real-time, which Visual Studio Add-in's do not support this functionality, as their behavior is "click the button to work".

Comment: Could you give a little more detail as to what you're trying to accomplish? What do you mean by "passively and in real-time?"

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant is that I want my code to work the time IDE is running. When I highlight a section of text, I want my code to log the selected text to a file on it's own, without the user manually logging it himself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the docs here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885240(v=VS.100).aspx

may be one useful starting point.

Answer (score 1):

See [my response to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688616/how-can-i-write-a-plugin-for-vs2010-using-mef/2688728#2688728).

The answer is "yes", this is possible/supported.  Look for the following in samples/documentation/walkthroughs:

`IWpfTextViewCreationLister` - for detecting when editor instances are created.
`ITextView.Selection` - the selection object
`ITextSelection.SelectionChanged` - raised whenever the selection changes (though not for the empty-selection tracking the caret)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is possible in .NET without going 'close to the metal', probably a reference to 'lower level code'. The .NET Method `TextPattern.GetSelection Method` will help you to accomplish your task if combined with a MouseEvent Handler.

Comment: Thanks you for the help Stephan, but the purpose I am doing this is to code it for Visual Studio 2010 as an extension, and I write it in C#. Since MEF appears to one of my solutions, I need some assistance on it, as I am still new to Visual Studio Add-in and MEF Extensiblity APIs

Comment: No problem buddy. I would use a C# MouseEvent Listener and the C# TextPattern.GetSelection Method I mentioned above.