# Visual Studio Editor, MEF in-Depth

Tags: visual-studio, resources, editor, mef, vsx

I have been having difficulty simply writing a Visual Studio Editor Extension with MEF (Managed Extensiblity Framework). I thank those who answered my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977272/visual-studio-2010-with-managed-extensiblity-framework), as they helped me know that I need to work with MEF.

I've been trying to learn MEF for the Visual Studio Editor from MSDN's page, [Extending the Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885242.aspx), but it appears that I have a hard time understanding it. Can anyone provide strong resource or tutorials in addressing problem such as using the right ContentTypeDefintion (IGlyphFactory, TextMarkTag, etc...), and what is a ITagger.

I need to understand these things, as most of the walkthrough only extending the text, such as only using the "spans" functionality, while I need to use "selection" methods and use MouseEventHandlers.

Does anyone know an example similiar to my example, or references can tell me something about MEF's for VS editor in-depth?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a couple of additional resources for learning more about editor extensibility.

- [Visual Studio 2010 Editor Extensibility Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsx)
- [Chris Granger's talk on Language Integration in the 2010 Editor](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/VSIPMarketing/VSX212-Adding-a-Language-Service-into-Visual-Studio-2010/)
- [Chris Granger's talk on Lighting up the editor with extensions](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/VSIPMarketing/VSX103-Lighting-up-the-new-Visual-Studio-2010-Editor-with-Rich-Extensions/)
- [Visual Studio Editor Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor) on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to integrate a new language into Visual Studio 2010. You could start watching this video:

[How to integrate a language service (Video)](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/vsipmarketing/vsx212-adding-a-language-service-into-visual-studio-2010)

Hope it helps!