# Blog and ref recommendations for vs2010 Extensibility

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I know this could be a potentially wide open topic but are there any good blogs, tutorials, guides or references for visual Studio Extensibility related material. I've swam through msdn and seen a couple potentially good guides provided I already know what I'm doing with the materials but, as far as starting off without getting lost is there anything out there?

Comment: If this is about an editor extension, see [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688616/how-can-i-write-a-plugin-for-vs2010-using-mef/2688728#2688728).

Comment: Funny meeting you here (the [tutorials] tag eradication, that is)

Comment: Yep I'm still lurking around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found Carlos Quintero's blog to be one of the best places for a huge variety of useful information on VS extendability:
http://msmvps.com/blogs/carlosq/

Also the MSDN page on VS extensibility is a good starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/vextend.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Well I guess I'll start....

- [This is a nice start into VS2010 Package Development and is pretty damn hefty and informative](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2010/03/02/VisualStudioPackages.aspx)
- [This one talks about using Dynamic commands in UI Context and as it goes along it gets into modifying other menus in the IDE...](http://blogs.rev-net.com/ddewinter/2008/03/14/dynamic-menu-commands-in-visual-studio-packages-part-1/)
- [This is an one is for using MEF for noobs and hits a number of different areas including working with silverlight](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2010/01/09/mef-for-beginner-toc.aspx)
- [This set is freakin gold. LearnVSXNow is a 44 (and counting) series of articles covering old and new stuff from MPF to MEF. A vertible treasure trove of Visual Studio Extensibility knowledge to pillage. YARR!](http://learnvsxnow.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LearnVSXNowOld&referringTitle=Home)
- [The Holy Grail of msdn refs for DTE Objects and the Stucture. Yes it says vs2003 but they are all made to be backwards compatible but words do not describe how helpful this has been](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291104%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)